# phpmyadmin on duplicate key update errors

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

So I'm trying to write an sql query to be execute from php to count number of downloads of a files. I have a table id,name,count and I want it to check if the name exists and increment count else to insert a new row.

I was trying to use if exists but that didn't work so now I'm trying to use the on duplicate key update statement. I inserted a row with the name lemons as a test case. I keep getting the error with my syntax near the WHERE statement. Am I approaching this right?

```
INSERT INTO `table` (`name`, `count`)
VALUES ('lemons',1) ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE  `count` = `count`+1
WHERE `name` = 'lemons';
```

Comment: You don't need a `where` there.

Comment: I removed where and the query executes, but it's just adding another row each time it's not actually checking the duplicate properly

Comment: Then the row does not have a unique-index

Comment: So I made the name column unique and suddenly we are in business

Answer (score 0):

If looks like phpmyadmin doesn't recognize the ON DUPLICATE KEY sentence. I have a symilar trouble.